# Material UI "with styles" with babel, styles broken

Tags: css, reactjs, babeljs, material-ui

We are using babel and lerna to keep certain elements of our react web app seperate. It's been working really well so far but seems to be having issues with styling when we create the static build.

Our core project is not run through babel and does not have any reference to babel.

Our separated components have the following babel dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    ...
  }
```

And we use the following config file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
    ],
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react'
    ]
};
```

We then run this command `./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/ -d ./dist/ --copy-files` to create our "babelised" package which we symlink into the core app using `lerna`.

We use material-ui for most of our components and we use the `withStyles(style)(Component)` syntax to attach inline CSS to our components.

If I run `npm start` on the core project everything works well and as expected however, when we create a build using `npm run-script build` and launch that, all the styling in the "babelised" component is broken.

Has anyone experienced this / have an idea why it's happening?

UPDATE:

As requested this is an example of the styles we are using in the react app:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  spinner: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    "margin-left": "calc(50% - 25px)"
  },
  topDiv: {
    display: "flex",
    "align-items": "center",
    width: "100%",
    "padding-bottom": "10px",
    "font-size": "40px",
    color: "white",
    "font-family": "Univia Pro, sans-serif",
    "font-weight": "350",
    "text-shadow": "0.02em 0.02em rgb(91, 91, 91, 0.75)",
    "border-style": "none none solid none",
    "border-width": "2px",
    "margin-bottom": "30px"
  },
  dataImport: {
    margin: "0px 10px 0px 10px"
  },

  paper: {
    width: "25%",
    "max-height": "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)",
    padding: "20px",
    "font-size": "13px",
    "overflow-y": "scroll"
  },
  instructionsDiv: {
    "border-style": "none none solid none",
    "border-width": "2px",
    "border-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
  },
  informationDiv: {
    "border-style": "none none solid none",
    "border-width": "2px",
    "border-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
  },
  buttonsDiv: {
    display: "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "align-items": "center"
  },
  pluginStoreButton: {
    color: "white",
    "background-color": "#CFD134",
    margin: "15px 0px 15px 0px",
    width: "255px",
    "&:hover": {
      "background-color": "#b6b742"
    }
  },
  integrationStoreButton: {
    color: "white",
    "background-color": "#2699FB",
    "margin-bottom": "10px",
    width: "255px",
    "&:hover": {
      "background-color": "#2f7cbf"
    }
  },
  emailTeamButton: {
    "margin-top": "10px",
    "background-color": "#EDF3F0",
    "&:hover": {
      "background-color": "#c9d3ce"
    },
    color: "#186A3B",
    "font-size": "11px",
    width: "260px"
  }
});
```

And we are using the Material-UI `withStyles` higher order component like so:

`export default withStyles(styles)(MyClass);`

When it's run through babel we get something like:

```
var styles = function styles(theme) {
  return {
    spinner: {
      margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
      "margin-left": "calc(50% - 25px)"
    },
    topDiv: {
      display: "flex",
      "align-items": "center",
      width: "100%",
      "padding-bottom": "10px",
      "font-size": "40px",
      color: "white",
      "font-family": "Univia Pro, sans-serif",
      "font-weight": "350",
      "text-shadow": "0.02em 0.02em rgb(91, 91, 91, 0.75)",
      "border-style": "none none solid none",
      "border-width": "2px",
      "margin-bottom": "30px"
    },
    dataImport: {
      margin: "0px 10px 0px 10px"
    },
    paper: {
      width: "25%",
      "max-height": "100%",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)",
      padding: "20px",
      "font-size": "13px",
      "overflow-y": "scroll"
    },
    instructionsDiv: {
      "border-style": "none none solid none",
      "border-width": "2px",
      "border-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
    },
    informationDiv: {
      "border-style": "none none solid none",
      "border-width": "2px",
      "border-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
    },
    buttonsDiv: {
      display: "flex",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "justify-content": "center",
      "align-items": "center"
    },
    pluginStoreButton: {
      color: "white",
      "background-color": "#CFD134",
      margin: "15px 0px 15px 0px",
      width: "255px",
      "&:hover": {
        "background-color": "#b6b742"
      }
    },
    integrationStoreButton: {
      color: "white",
      "background-color": "#2699FB",
      "margin-bottom": "10px",
      width: "255px",
      "&:hover": {
        "background-color": "#2f7cbf"
      }
    },
    emailTeamButton: {
      "margin-top": "10px",
      "background-color": "#EDF3F0",
      "&:hover": {
        "background-color": "#c9d3ce"
      },
      color: "#186A3B",
      "font-size": "11px",
      width: "260px"
    }
  };
};
```

And: `var _default = (0, _withStyles.default)(styles)(MyClass);`

`_withStyles` is imported like so: `var _withStyles = _interopRequireDefault(require("@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"));`

There are no error messages but it is clear that the styling has gone as the layout is completely unusable.

Comment: could you include the code that is using `withStyles` and how that is being used in your app? Also could you paste whatever error messages you are seeing? Thank you!

Comment: @RudolfOlah I've updated the question to include that info.

Comment: @RobSanders did you find a resolution to your issue ?  I have the same issue and noticed that the babel compiled version has the order of the class name out of order. So that the default style are overriding my custom styles.

Comment: @Vlad ah interesting. No I never found a solution, I have put it into the pile of things to look at in the future :) ! Did you manage to rearrange your imports successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this plugin in your `.babelrc` :

```
["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
```

Comment: Tried this but no change unfortunately.

Comment: What is your import declaration for `withStyles` ?

Comment: If your style is in separate file, you need to export this. 
Ex : `const styles = theme => ({...}); export default styles;`

And in your component you can do this : 
`import myStyles from "./styles.jsx"`
`import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

And then you can do :
`export default withStyles(myStyles)(MyClass);`

Comment: The `import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";` is as you've got it here. They style is in the same file not in a different one.

Comment: Can you paste your `package.json` content here, especially the line where "scripts" have been declared : `"scripts" : {"start": ..., "dev": ..., "build": ..., test:....},` ?

Comment: ```{
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.4.3",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0"
  }
}```

Comment: The command I am using to build is `./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/ -d ./dist/ --copy-files`